# How can I add a seperator to a Listview in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to add a seperator to a listview and I'm not sure how to go about it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: VCL or FM? What viewstyle? Don't hesitate to give more details.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. As @MBo says, we need to know the kind of app you are making (VCL or Firemonkey), as well as the mode (view style) of the list view. But even then, it isn't quite clear to me what you mean by "separator". Perhaps you could draw a picture of the desired result?

Comment: VCL using vsReport

Comment: What is stopping you from simply adding a blank list item?  Or using groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`TListView`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView) control is a wrapper for the Win32 [`ListView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview) control. This is a very feature-rich control. Many, but not all, of its features are supported by the VCL wrapper.

One of the list view's abilities is to divide its items into *groups*. Fortunately, the VCL makes this very easy.

- Right-click the control and choose **Groups Editor** to create groups.
- Right-click the control and choose **Items Editor** to create items and assign them to groups.
- Set the control's **GroupView** property to `True` using the **Object Inspector**.

Group view works for all view styles except `vsList`.

[image: Screenshot of a list view control with groups.]

Comment: Don't forget to set the `TListView.GroupView` property to True in order to use groups. And, of course, groups can also be managed in code too, using the `TListView.Groups` and `TListItem.GroupID` properties.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Didn't I mention `GroupView`? :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that.